# Raycast, unity, обращение raycast hit

Tags: c#, unity3d

Народ, есть проблема, делаю игру, где мне при нажатии на объект необходимо менять состояние другого, выдает ошибку:

Assets\ground\GroungSpawner.cs(23,83): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Вот сам скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class TapController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        hitController();
    }

    void hitController()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Gcollider")
                {
                    hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<cellManager>().active = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот скрипт, к которому обращаюсь:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cellManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool stage;
    public GameObject active;
    void Start()
    {
        stage = false;
    }

    void Update()
   {
        active.SetActive(stage);
   }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно ты не попадаешь в коллайдер этого объекта, проверь. Возможно у тебя не стоит коллайдер, или ты попадаешь в дочерний объект.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня луч попадал в дочерний объект.